# Unable to configure Dataduct wrapper for AWS Datapipes

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have the config file in place in the Dataduct directory. But the error i get is config file missing. Can someone please suggest, if I am missing on something.

Answer (score 0):

I know, the answer is late for the author, but perhaps someone else need that. 
Based on dataduct documentation the config should be placed into one of this places:

```
 1. /etc/dataduct.cfg 
 2. ~/.dataduct/dataduct.cfg 
 3. DATADUCT_CONFIG_PATH - environment variable
```

I place it into the .dataduct folder in user home (second case) and it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Hi Viktor, I configured things as mentioned. but i'm getting error as - No module named dataduct.steps.executors.runner. could you please let me know whether anything i'm missing